# how do you pass array and str and date on javascript function parameter?

Tags: javascript

How do I make this work?
Date is `YYYY-MM-DD`.
When called function `testFunction(2021-01-01, Peter, [Chicago, New York]);`
Output should be something like this.

- Time: 2021-01-01
- Name: Peter
- City: Chicago, New York

```
function testFunction(date, str, arr) {
  console.log("time: " + date );
  console.log("name: " + str);
  console.log("city: " + arr);
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: just studying.. it seems only passing number works but it won't concatenation with string.. and i can't pass string value either. :(

Comment: Well you can convert the array to string like this arr.join(", "). Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use one variable to store the array and pass that into the function:

```js
function testFunction(date, str, arr) {
    console.log("time: " + date );
    console.log("name: " + str);
    console.log("city: " + arr.join(', '));
}
var time = '2021-01-01'
var name = 'Peter';
var city = ['Chicago', 'New York'];
testFunction(time, name, city);
```